# Android notification builder getNotification() vs build()

Tags: android, notifications

According to the documentation that I've seen, the android notification builder was introduced in API 11, and:

- In API 11 to API 15, one uses the method .getNotification() to create the notification object
- In API 16 onwards, one uses the .build() to create the notificaiton object.

That sounds straightforward enough, but how do I write code in Eclipse that'll call the right method depending on the API version?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your app supports devices older than API Level 11, you should be using `NotificationCompat.Builder`, in which case you can just use `build()` all of the time.

Otherwise, you are welcome to just call `getNotification()`, until such time as you are willing to support only API Level 16 and higher. They simply renamed the method for greater consistency. If you look at [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Notification.java), `getNotification()` just calls `build()` on newer devices.

There's nothing wrong with using Raghav's approach, and that sort of technique will be required in other situations where there are API level differences.

Answer (score 5):

You can check the API level at Runtime.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
  // call something for API Level 16+
} else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  // call something for API Level 11+
}
```